# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

It's frustrating me right now!

I created an application initially for restore/backup databases in C#.NET and it did work before but somehow it is not working right now; even though my code is the same.

I am getting error message Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException and I have been searching for the solution to this error message for hours.

Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code-

```
            //call restore class
            Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

            //set the restore type to a database restore 
            sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

            //select database
            Database db = sqlServer.Databases["database"];

            //stop all process on specific database
            sqlServer.KillAllProcesses("database");

            //Backup device type i.e. backup file 
            BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\" + _filename, DeviceType.File);

            //add device type to restore class 
            sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);

            //if database already exists, replace it 
            sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;               

            //perform the restore 
            sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

Comment: Can you post the Exception.Message as well as which line is causing the exception?

Comment: Couldn't help notice that you write to `Program Files`. Unless you are running as Administrator, your app doesn't have rights to write there, on Windows Vista and newer, with UAC enabled.

Comment: There is a SmoExceptionType property in FailedOperationException  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.failedoperationexception.aspx?ppud=4).  Here is a list of the enum values for that type:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoexceptiontype.aspx.  This should help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Error Message- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException. Also, UAC is turned off.

Comment: @RushabhShah that's the type. What's the message?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing backup file other than Program Files. As I presume you are working on Windows Vista/7. File operation on this folder requires administration rights. To check if this is the issue I'd recommend you something like this:

```
string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP").ToString() + "\\" + _filename;
BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(path, DeviceType.File);
```

Comment: I did tried to do restore as per your suggestion but it works sometime only. Suppose, if I open application after couple of minute it will generate error message of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing "database name" database.

If, I close everything and tried to do restore then it did work. This drives me crazy as I am not able to get any proper solution or error message. 

Can you suggest me some proper suggestion

Comment: Also, I am getting same error if I do it from Management Tools.